# Select item having maximum from sqlalchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

Given this pair of classes:

```
class Thing(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class ThingInfo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Thing))
    recorded_at = Column(DateTime)

    thing = relationship(Thing, backref='all_info')
```

How can I define a property `Thing.newest_info` to achieve:

```
t = s.query(Thing).first()
newest_info = max(t.all_info, key=lambda i: i.recorded_at)
print newest_info

#equivalent to:
t = s.query(Thing).first()
print t.newest_info
```

I'd like to do this with a `column_property` or `relationship`, not a normal `property`. So far what I have is:

```
select([ThingInfo])
  .group_by(ThingInfo.thing)
  .having(func.max(ThingInfo.recorded_at))
```

But I can't figure out how to attach this as a propery of a single `Thing` object.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `order_by` clause to the relationship and this becomes trivial:

```
class ThingInfo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Thing))
    recorded_at = Column(DateTime)

    thing = relationship(Thing, backref=backref('all_info', order_by='ThingInfo.recorded_at')

thing = session.query(Thing).get(id)
newest_info = thing.all_info[-1]
```

or alternatively `backref=backref('all_info', order_by='desc(ThingInfo.recorded_at)')` and `newest_info=thing.all_info[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a working attempt:

```
t = aliased(ThingInfo)
ThingInfo.is_newest = column_property(
    select([
        ThingInfo.recorded_at == func.max(t.recorded_at)
    ])
    .select_from(r)
    .where(t.thing_id == ThingInfo.thing_id)
)

Thing.newest_info = relationship(
    ThingInfo,
    viewonly=True,
    uselist=False,
    primaryjoin=(ThingInfo.thing_id == Thing.id) & ThingInfo.is_newest
)
```

Things I dislike about this:

- I'm having to specify how to join `Thing`s to `ThingInfo`s in a second place
- I'm trying to work out how to write this to use a groubby