# Correlating a SQLAlchemy relationship with an awkward join

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_remote = Column(UnicodeText)

class B:
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foreign_to_a = Column(UnicodeText)
    maximum_a = relationship(A, primaryjoin=lambda:
      and_(remote(a_remote) == foreign(foreign_to_a),
           A.a_id = select([func.max(A.a_id)]).where(A.a_remote == B.foreign_to_a))
    )
```

In words, I'm trying to create a relationship `maximum_a` with the largest `a_id` of all the A's pointed to by a given B. I specifically want this to be a relationship so that I can prefetch it with `joinedload` to avoid a case where we now have O(N) queries.

When I try to preload the `maximum_a` relationship (e.g. via `session.query(B).options(joinedload('maximum_a')).all()`), I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Select statement 'SELECT max(a_1.a_id) AS max_1
FROM a AS a_1, b
WHERE a_1.a_remote = b.foreign_to_a' returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate(<tables>) to control correlation manually.
```

I've tried to read the SQLA docs on correlation, but they're all written in terms of the raw `select` rather than ORM calls, and the descriptions are not very clear, so I'm not sure where to add the `correlate` call--or if there's a better way to do this.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at [inheritence and polymorphic loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance)

Comment: Can you expand on how that's relevant? This problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with inheritance or polymorphism.

Comment: Sorry, Ben. I may have misread this question. I was suggesting inheritance as a means of getting the desired result, but after rereading the question, I don't think it fits your case.

Comment: Please take a look at following posts (just using google search): 1. [Select item having maximum from sqlalchemy relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28155414/99594) 2. [versions.py](https://gist.github.com/deontologician/8744532) 3. [RelationshipToLatest Recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/RelationshipToLatest)

Comment: Huh--the recipe didn't work for me due to an error about SELECTs in join conditions (perhaps a Postgres-specific problem)? Anyway, it got me to realize that I could try to move the SELECT out of the join condition by using a secondary join, which eventually led me to a solution, so thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much trying, here's what worked:

```
class A:
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_remote = Column(UnicodeText)

latest_a = select([
    func.max(A.a_id).label('a_id'), A.a_remote
]).group_by(A.a_remote).alias('latest_a')

class B:
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foreign_to_a = Column(UnicodeText)
    maximum_a = relationship(A,
        secondary=latest_a,
        primaryjoin=latest_a.c.a_remote == foreign_to_a,
        secondaryjoin=latest_a.c.a_id == A.a_id,
        uselist=False, viewonly=True)
```